# How do you report Time using Google Play Social API?

Tags: c#, android, api, unity-game-engine

**Hey!**

I want to use google play leaderboards in my game. But I don't have score, I have time. So I want to report the lowest value (the fastest time) to the API, but method for reporting (Social.ReportScore) has an argument with a long value, and I don't want to report just whole numbers, I want decimal. Does anybody know, how to report time to google play leaderboards in decimal places (00.000)?

[Screenshot of the Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YOpu.png)

```
public void ReportScore(float score, string leaderboardID)
{

    Social.ReportScore(score, leaderboardID, (bool succes) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Reported score to leaderboard: " + succes.ToString());
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want decimal places?

Comment: You can represent 1.5 seconds as 1500(Miliseconds)

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, thanks! :D